# creating a new column in R based off information already in the dataframe

Tags: r

hello this is a basic question as I am new to R

I have an existing column within my dataframe called "shade" with different shades of pink, i want a new column called "basic colour" which prints PINK if the field contains a shade of pink. Same for shades of blue and green.

How would I do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: As somebody has already mentioned, it would be better to show what code you have tried so far or what you are looking for as desired output.

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
df1$basic_color <- ifelse(grepl("pink", df1$shade), "PINK", NA_character_)
```